# How to make Nhibernate generate table with Text field instead of nvarchar(255)

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I'm trying to make NHibernate generate my schema/SQL 2008, and using the mapping below it keeps wanting to create an nvarchar(255) column instead of text...any ideas?

```
    <property name="AnnouncementText" column="AnnouncementText" type="StringClob">
  <column name="AnnouncementText" sql-type="NTEXT"/>
</property>
```

Thanks!

Comment: wow 43 minutes from question posting to insertion in Google index...how does that happen???? Went searching for more hits and my own dang question came back.

Comment: SO must have some sort of pact with the devil... I mean, Google ;-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is specifying the name of the column twice...once I took it and the length out of the property element it worked perfectly

```
 <property name="AnnouncementText" type="StringClob">
  <column name="AnnouncementText" sql-type="text"/>
</property>
```

Comment: That's the problem, thanks I was looking around for a silly question like this one!

Answer (score 6):

I'm used to SQL Server 2005 and the dialect it uses, but I presume you can do something similar. Since nvarchar(n) allows n up to 4000, a value above this will use nvarchar(max).

I *presume* that SQL Server 2000, which it sounds like you're using, does something similar once you hit the limit. If I read the NHibernate code correctly (NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2000Dialect..ctor()) you get ntext once you pass  0xFA0 = 4000 characters.

```
<property name="AnnouncementText" column="AnnouncementText" type="string" length="10000"/>
```

Comment: Ooops forgot to mention I'm using SQL 2008 but with the 2005 dialect, but I'm actually trying to make a Text column, not an nvarchar(max).

Comment: Btw, you should consider changing your text/ntext columns no varchar(max)/nvarchar(max) in 2005 and 2008 as the formers are being deprecated.

Answer (score -2):

this won't help at all, but I remember the good old days  ;-)...

```
create table YourTable
(
    ...
    AnnouncementText     text null
    ...

)
```

Comment: awh come on! I just find it so ironic that you have to struggle so hard to make a fancy auto-magical tool like NHibernate do something so simple!